# Dynamically Select Columns and Summaries Data

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data frame

```
ID <- c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Value1 <- c(20,50,30,10,15,10,NA)
Value2 <- c(40,33,84,NA,20,1,NA)
Value3 <- c(60,40,60,10,25,NA,NA)
Grade1 <- c(20,50,30,10,15,10,NA)
Grade2 <- c(40,33,84,NA,20,1,NA)

DF <- data.frame(ID,Value1,Value2,Value3,Grade1,Grade2)

  ID Value1 Value2 Value3 Grade1 Grade2
1  1     20     40     60     20     40
2  1     50     33     40     50     33
3  2     30     84     60     30     84
4  3     10     NA     10     10     NA
5  4     15     20     25     15     20
6  5     10      1     NA     10      1
7  6     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

I would like to group by ID, select columns with names contain the string ("Value"), and get the mean of these columns with NA not included.

Here is an example of the desired output

```
ID     mean(Value)
1      41
2      58
3      10
....
```

In my attempt to solve this challenge, I wrote the following code

```
Library(tidyverse)    
DF %>% group_by (ID) %>% select(contains("Value")) %>% summarise(mean(.,na.rm = TRUE))
```

The code groups the data by IDs, select columns with column name containing ("Value"), and attempts to summarise the selected columns by using the mean function. When I run my code, I get the following output

```
> DF %>% group_by (ID) %>% select(contains("Value")) %>% summarise(mean(.))
Adding missing grouping variables: `ID`
# A tibble: 6 x 2
     ID `mean(.)`
  <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1        NA
2     2        NA
3     3        NA
4     4        NA
5     5        NA
6     6        NA
```

I would appreciate your help in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using `pivot_longer` to get your data from wide to long form Read latest tidyR update on `pivot_longer` & `pivot_wider` (https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html)

```
library(tidyverse)

ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
Value1 <- c(50,30,10,15,10,NA)
Value2 <- c(33,84,NA,20,1,NA)
Value3 <- c(40,60,10,25,NA,NA)

DF <- data.frame(ID,Value1,Value2,Value3)

DF %>% pivot_longer(-ID) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% summarise(mean=mean(value,na.rm=TRUE))
```

Output here

```
   ID  mean
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  41  
2     2  58  
3     3  10  
4     4  20  
5     5  5.5
6     6 NaN
```

Comment: Could please explain why are you using pivot functions? Is it possible to solve this issue by grouping?

Comment: I have used grouping but after pivoting because your data is in wide format. To group the data, we need it in long form (Read this for Wide Vs Long data understanding https://discuss.analyticsvidhya.com/t/difference-between-wide-and-long-data-format/8110#targetText=For%20converting%20data%20to%20wide,in%20R%20use%20Reshape2%20package%20.&targetText=Wide%20data%20has%20a%20column,the%20values%20of%20those%20variables.)

Answer (score 0):

Without using dplyr or any specific package, this would help :

```
DF$mean<- rowMeans(DF[,c(2:4)], na.rm = T)
```

Comment: Your solution assumes columns' index is static. I want to avoid this issue by searching using column name.

Comment: If ID is always present you can use :
DF$avg <- rowMeans(DF %>% select(-ID), na.rm = T)